Multiple PDF iteration in ReactJS
The goal is to have a page that presents all of my locally stored pdf's names, each one of them would be clickable and would open the pdf in a new tab. (I also tried to store them in my MongoDB db but I found that to be even harder)
With only one/a few pdfs, I can just use import pdf from 'path/file.pdf' but if I don't know the exact number I want to display and I want my page to adapt to the number of files, then I have no idea how to get to all my pdf correctly imported so they are supported by React and clickable. (I tried to add the following function in my Express API but as the links are not imported as supported by React, it doesn't open them)
Express API :
app.get('/procedures', async (req, res) => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath).map((name) => {
        
            return {
                nom: name,
                lien: `../client/src/ressources/${name}`,
            };
        
        
    });
    res.send(files);    
})

my code in React :
{listeProcedures.map((p, index) => {
   if((q === "" || p.nom.toLowerCase().includes(q.toLowerCase()) ) ){
      return (
        <div className="procedureContainer">
           <a href='../ressources/Rapport_proco.pdf' type='application/pdf' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
             <ModuleCard key={index} text={p.nom.toUpperCase()} style="flex-end" fontsize={15} />
           </a>
           <Button sx={{ position: 'absolute', top: '25px', right: '10px', display: `${afficherBin}` }} onClick={() => handleSupprService(s)} className="deleteFav"><img src={bin} alt="" /></Button>   
       </div>
            )}
          })}

I tried to import the whole directory which contains my pdfs in React, I also tried to store all pdfs in my MongoDB db but didn't succeed as storing the relative paths and then returning them with express would only result in the same issue, the links are not opening the pdf in React if the file is not imported.
